# Copy paste from Windows (host OS) to Linux Mint in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using Windows 8.1 and I want to copy text from my Windows (host) to Linux Mint in Oracle VirtualBox but I can't. I already picked "Bidirectional" for "drag n drop" and "shared clipboard" in the advanced settings, but I still can't copy and paste.

Comment: Do you have VirtualBox Guest Additions installed on Linux?

Comment: how do i check?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the contrib repository enabled in Linux Mint, the vbox guest addition may be available there for you to install using `apt`. That's the best way to be installed.

So, try:

`sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-x11` in terminal. If that won't work check your repos for `contrib`.

I'm not certain if they are available on all versions of Linux Mint, you didn't mention version.

If the package is not there, you should first install some other packages, `sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and then follow the advice, in the VM window, click on the Devices menu and select Insert Guest Additions CD Image. Then mount the cd, and execute `sudo /{path of mounted cd image}/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`.

I may be missing something on the latter, if you search the net you'll find lots of links.

Comment: Could not mount the media/drive 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).


Kode Hasil: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Komponen: 
ConsoleWrap
Antar Muka: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
Pemanggil: 
IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}

Comment: Im using linux mint Cinnamon 19.3. i installed the packages.but when i clicked Insert Guest Additions cd image this Error Poped

Comment: Media locked, apparently some other cd/dvd is inserted to VM's virtual cd drive. Vbox tries to eject it; in Linux this is not allowed, it must be unmounted first. To be sure, shutdown the VM, empty any cd from drive (either iso, or virtual drive connected to physical drive) and start it. Then the virtual additions iso should inserted.

Comment: The 1st proposal, `sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-x11` didn't work? If it did, you don't need the rest.